# xen + debian network after upgrade squeeze to wheeze

Tags: networking, debian, xen

I've got a Debian + Xen server.
After a system upgrade to the stable version the network doesn't come up after boot. Every time after reboot I need to bring it up manually. The network configuration was not changed during upgrade.

Here is /etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 11.22.33.44
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 11.22.33.1
    nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

After boot `ip r` shows no route and `eth0` has no ip address.
Manually ip and route setup goes fine and network starts working.

Messages from `dmesg` about network I've found (looks like nothing interesting)

```
[    3.894401] ACPI: Fan [FAN3] (off)
[    3.894444] ACPI: Fan [FAN4] (off)
[    4.178348] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: eth0: (PCI Express:2.5GT/s:Width x1) 00:1e:67:14:66:c9
[    4.178351] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: eth0: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
[    4.178392] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: eth0: MAC: 10, PHY: 11, PBA No: 0100FF-0FF
[    4.178413] e1000e 0000:02:00.0: Disabling ASPM L0s L1
[    4.178432] xen: registering gsi 16 triggering 0 polarity 1
--
[    4.223667] ata5: DUMMY
[    4.223668] ata6: DUMMY
[    4.289153] e1000e 0000:02:00.0: eth1: (PCI Express:2.5GT/s:Width x1) 00:1e:67:14:66:c8
[    4.289155] e1000e 0000:02:00.0: eth1: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
[    4.289245] e1000e 0000:02:00.0: eth1: MAC: 3, PHY: 8, PBA No: 1000FF-0FF
[    4.506908] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci_hcd
[    4.542920] ata2: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
--
[   10.362999] EXT4-fs (dm-23): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[   10.419103] EXT4-fs (dm-3): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[   10.988255] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth1: link is not ready
[   13.175533] Event-channel device installed.
[   13.287555] XENBUS: Unable to read cpu state
--
[   13.288670] XENBUS: Unable to read cpu state
[   13.965939] Bridge firewalling registered
[   14.134048] e1000e: eth1 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx
[   14.283862] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): peth0: link is not ready
[   14.284543] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth1: link becomes ready
[   17.800627] e1000e: peth0 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx
[   17.801377] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): peth0: link becomes ready
[   18.307278] device peth0 entered promiscuous mode
[   24.538899] eth1: no IPv6 routers present
[   28.570902] peth0: no IPv6 routers present
```

I've upgraded two servers and I've such behaviour on two of them. How to fix this and get network starts automatically on boot?

Answer (score 0):

You need to either switch the etnernet cable to the other ethernet port or change eth0 to eth1 in your configuration. The reason is you have two ethernet interfaces and right now you're configuring the interface that does not have a cable.

Note the

> e1000e: eth1 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx

You can also try to delete ***/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules*** and/or changing the contents so as to reflect whatever you want it to be. That file decides on which network interface gets what name. Reboot for changes or deleting to take effect. Deleting is fine, it will be regenerated.

By the way, the dmesg messages also show ***peth0*** so it may just be that udev renamed eth0 to peth0. Deletion or changing of ***/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules*** would take care of that as well. Or change ***eth0*** to ***peth0*** in your configuration.

> [   17.801377] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): peth0: link becomes ready

Comment: Unfortunately the same issue occurs on the server with only one ethernet port. I will provide logs from after a while ( just right I'll get direct access ).

Comment: I bet on that server the interface name was changed by udev on boot. The solution above would apply in this case as well.